# Diagnostic tests of the GLM models

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, inference, linear-model

"We can only claim that the negative binomial model is the best among the three considered models. But, this does not imply that the negative binomial model fits the data well. In fact, Table 2 can be regarded as showing that all three models do not fit the data properly. "

I don't understand the above comment. However, I did present diagnostic plots to show the model fit. It failed to convince my professor. I was wondering if you could guide me to counter this comment. I appreciate your suggestions.

[image]

Here is the diagnostic plot for the negative binomial model:

[image]

The sample size was 70 and 4 predictors were used to fit the model. Here is the portion of the R output to see the degrees of freedom for the Negative Binomial model:

```
(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.6468) family taken to be 1)
## 
##     Null deviance: 129.591  on 69  degrees of freedom
## Residual deviance:  85.542  on 65  degrees of freedom
## AIC: 1418.9
## 
## Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1
## 
## 
##               Theta:  0.6468 
##           Std. Err.:  0.0925 
## 
##  2 x log-likelihood:  -1406.9020
```

Comment: You need to tell us more details, at least sample size, degrees of freedom, maybe some diagnostic plots, ... without that not much to do ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have added additional info. Thank you so much for your suggestions.